# GroupBox's ControlTemplate and RowDefinitions's Height

Tags: wpf, xaml, groupbox

I was learning how to change the ControlTemplate and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151979/does-the-groupbox-header-in-wpf-swallow-mouse-clicks?rq=1). I copied the ControlTemplate and created a GroupBox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyTestApp.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="130" d:DesignWidth="250">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="CheckedGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}" ConverterParameter="7">
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="Header"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="3,1,3,0">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource CheckedGroupBoxStyle}">
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <CheckBox>GroupBox1</CheckBox>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Item A" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Text="Item B" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Text="Item C" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Text="Item D" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is there is a border around the Grid that's inside the GroupBox. It can be removed by changing Height="Auto" to Height="*" for RowDefinition. If I don't use the CheckedGroupBoxStyle, then the border will not show up either. I want know why because the aforementioned post says the resulting style is almost identical to the default template of the control.

[image: Border around the Grid inside GroupBox]

Comment: Have you correctly implemented the `BorderGapMaskConverter`?

Comment: aha, I didn't. I thought that's one of the default converters. I didn't implement it. Any pointer to where I can find the corrected implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have not added the `BorderGapMaskConverter` to your code example. After a quick search on MSDN, I found that it is in fact a `Converter` that is included in the .NET Framework. You can find details of it on the [`BorderGapMaskConverter` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.bordergapmaskconverter.aspx) page. You will be able to use it if you are using .NET 3.0 or above.

---

UPDATE >>>

No sorry, 'implemented' is no longer the correct word... initially, I thought that you would have to implement your own `Converter`. However, now that I found out that it is included in the .NET Framework, you just need to add a reference to it in your XAML `Resources` section like in the example in the other post:

```
<BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
```

Mind you, you *should* have had a warning in the Visual Studio Error List saying something like:

> The resource "BorderGapMaskConverter" could not be resolved.

Comment: I use .NET 4.0 so it is included. Does that mean the problem is not because I didn't implement BorderGapMaskConverter?

Comment: I do have a reference to the converter in the Resouorces section.

Comment: Then what error(s) are you getting in the Output Window in Visual Studio?